# Is "être de la jaquette volante" a derogatory term?

Tags: sens

I saw this term in "Les nouvelles aventures d'Aladin" in the context of "Serais-tu un peu de la jaquette volante?" and I translated it as "Do you swing the other way", which in english is non-offensive. If it is offensive what is the french equivalent to "to swing the other way"?

Comment: Quippy, if you believe any question of yours has been properly answered, do not hesitate to mark it as accepted!

Comment: @jlliagre, I don't know how to do that

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/182055

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had never heard of this movie and did a little search on line to check if my understanding was likely.  Indeed it is in keeping with what I could read online. And some critics say the film is homophobic.

***Être de la jaquette*** is a colloquial  (slightly derogatory) term to qualify a homosexual and not much used nowadays.

The original phrase is *être de la jaquette* or *être de la jaquette flottante* but some people say *de la jaquette volante* (I have found quotes with *jaquette volante* online but I do not want to link to them, those sites are too offensive). You can find the etymology and meaning of *être de la jaquette* on the [wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%AAtre_de_la_jaquette).

I think the translation you found ("Do you swing the other way?"), although it conveys the meaning, is too soft. I would translate "Do you swing the other way?" by: *es-tu de l'autre bord?*<sup>1</sup>

<sup><sup>1</sup>Être de l'autre bord [on the wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%AAtre_de_l%E2%80%99autre_bord), entry 2.</sup>

Comment: Sorry, I did mean être de la jaquette volante, but you've answered the question I had regardless, thanks :)

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: @Quippy Yes, much better. I've upvoted it. I've modified my answer to stick to the point but my explanation still holds.